# Como leer un archivo de texto con JavaScript sin cargarlo en input

Tags: javascript

Necesito una manera de acceder a un archivo local de mi pagina web con JavaScript sin usar un input para cargarlos, sino que lo localize directamente desde el JavaScript, necesito una manera de hacer esto que se muestra:

```
let archivo = loadFile("../notas.txt") 
document.getElementById('output').textContent = archivo;
```

y que retorne:

```
<pre id="output">Estas son las notas que he cargado</pre>
```

Comment: ¿[Has hecho una búsqueda en el sitio](/search?q=leer+archivo+[javascript])?

Comment: El archivo está en el servidor o es local?

Comment: El archivo está en el local